# can't get curl ssl_verify_result other than 0

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ftps

I'am trying to conect ftps remote server with certificate verification and then upload a file. But i can't make it. I think its something with certificate verification because all the time i receive ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) in curl_getinfo array. I don't know what to think about it. My curl options for cert verification for now are:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
```

When i erase cacert.pem file, after script execution i immediately receive curl error:

> error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: certs/unizetos.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs | 77

And ["ssl_verify_result"] => int(0)- in this case its OK. But when cacert.pem contains correct certificate, after script execution it keep runnin until:

> SSL connection timeout | 28

In this case it looks like the script goes through cert verify and meet another problem, but ["ssl_verify_result"] is all the time 0.

Q1. Whats the possible ssl_verify_result codes are?

Q2. In second case i described the cert verification is OK or not?

Comment: Have you thought about starting with http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php and then building up from there ? I'm unsure why your using CURL in an example you want to use a ftps protocal.

Comment: I tried with no effect, ftp_ssl_connect return false without any debug information. I thought it's because of message of certificate key accept which displays each time i connect with ftp client. And i cant find any option to play with it.

Comment: Have you verified your properly configuring your CURL Parameters to to use SFTP ?
I did see this question on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451985/adding-support-for-scp-and-sftp-for-curl-on-linux

Which may address some of your issues.